# How would I replicate this table in LaTeX? New to it :)

Tags: tables

How would I create this table in LaTeX with uniformly thin cell lines and get each element of the table to be centred in its own cell?

I have never made a table and I am pressed for time - I would appreciate any help at all. Many thanks :)[image: Cayley table]

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/tables

Comment: You can have a look at [link](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf) to start drawing your table. If you need some help, you should provide a minimum working example (MWE) with your code so we can answer specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few nontrivial tricks.

Fill it in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  |
  >{\columncolor{black!30}\sffamily}l
  |
  >{\sffamily\vphantom{\'A}}l
  |
  *{11}{>{\sffamily}l|}
}
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{white}}~ >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}| *{12}-}
\rowcolor{black!30}\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}}
  & I & P & Q & K & S & T & J & V & W & X & Y & Z \\
\hline
I & I & P & Q &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   \\
\hline
P & P & I & K &   &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   \\
\hline
  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & W &   \\
\hline
  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & W \\
\hline
  &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
  &   &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
  &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
W & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
  &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
  &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
  &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ever so much - I will try to learn how to code works to get the table :)

Comment: I am having some trouble using this code - i have installed the required packages but texmaker isn't liking it :( Do you have any idea what might be the cause of this? Many thanks

Comment: @TrivialGuy You're possibly missing `colortbl`.

Answer (score 2):

With the environment `NiceTabular` of `nicematrix`.

- The key `corners` specifies a list of corners. Here, there is only the corner NW (north-west).
- With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn excepted in the corners.
- The `\CodeBefore` contains instructions that are executed before the typesetting of the content of the array (and before the rules). The instructions for coloring rows and columns don't have any effect in the corners.

**However, you need several compilations.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{13}{l}}[corners=NW,hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{lightgray}{1}
  \columncolor{lightgray}{1}
\Body
  & I & P & Q & K & S & T & J & V & W & X & Y & Z \\
I & I & P & Q &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   \\
P & P & I & K &   &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & W &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & W \\
  &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
W & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & W &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]